# Regex url path - get specific numbers

Tags: regex, typescript, url, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get specific numbers (123456) from a three examples of URL path:

/aaa/bbb/co1-e3ee1ddd-3333s1-123456/art-1?unitId=art(1)par(5)

/aaa/bbb/cos-123456/art-1

/aaa/bbb/cos-123456?unitId=art(1)

I used (\d+) but it matches every number.

Comment: Why don't you want the `1` from `art-1`?

Comment: @Nick Because I need to return a part of URL path after these specific numbers

Comment: But how do you distinguish `123456` from `1`? They both occur in the same sort of places. What makes `123456` special?

Comment: It is document ID

Comment: But how does someone writing a regex know that `1` **isn't** a document nro?

Comment: Try `/\/co[^\/]*-(\d+)/`

Comment: If I knew it, I wouldn't ask :)

Comment: How can you describe the place in string where the numbers are to be extracted? How can you define the context? I assumed the subpart starts with `co`. Or is it something different?

Comment: Every word or number is a random example. This URL path is unique for every law document.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I make regex which finds min eight digits in a string (because document nro has min eight digits) and - for sure - I compare this with another regex results if will be and returns the longest result. It works but this is sensitive to changing the number of digits in the document nro. `urlWithoutRoutePath.match(new RegExp('(\\d{8,})\\b', 'ig'))`